# SVG Path to Polygon/Array of Points/Absolute coordinates

Tags: android, svg, path, polygon

In my app, I get a really long SVG path as a string. I need to convert this path to polygon or array of points (absolute coordinates).

All solutions I have found so far are based on Batik (I cannot use this in Android Studio), SVGPathElement (awt.svg also not applicable in android) or JavaScript libraries (Raphael etc.).

So my question is, is there any other possibility to use a function like getPointAtLength(x) to sample the path, or do I have to write programmatically a parser? I have searched for hours to find an answer, unfortunately unsuccessful. 
Thank you in advance!

Solution:
path = createPathFromPathData(String pathStr)
path.approximate(error);
returns an array of absolute points

Comment: Thanks, but the method createNodesFromPathData(String path) from PathParser.java doesn't work properly with my paths. 
Example: to String st = "M9070,15945l0,-55 -1689,0 -1690,0 -3,38 -3,37 -110,0 -110,0 -3,-37 -3,-38 -2730,0 -2729,0 0,-7945 0,-7945 6180,0 6180,0 0,7945 0,7945 -1595,0 -1595,0 0,55 0,55 -50,0 -50,0 0,-55z"; 
it returns an array with only 3 elements:
9070.0,15945.0 type M; 
0.0,-55.0 type l; 
z
This method works with substrings and I think it doesn`t work correctly if one point is more than once in the path (like in my example)

Comment: @pskink the logcat output is:  
 clickMethod 3;  
    clickMethod M 2;  
    clickMethod l 48;  
    clickMethod z 0